# Detecting plant disease by remote sensing

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation

I want to develop a workflow to detect a specific disease in potato plants by remote sensing.

I have acquired the images of the potato field by mounting a multispectral camera on a drone that flew at an altitude of 5m above the plants.

The multispectral camera has 5 bands namely: Blue,Green,Red,NIR and RedEdge.

I have converted the DN(raw digital number) values of all bands in reflectance values.

I have first trained SVM to segment soil from plants and then also applied SAVI(soil adjusted vegetation index) to refine soil segmentation from plants.

Now, I want to apply NDVI(normalized difference vegetation index) to determine the heath of plants pixel wise.

Is it the right approach to follow? Will NDVI be resonable to apply on images taken at just 5m height? Or is there any better approach?

Best regards...

Comment: I don't think anyone of us has a potatoe field and an airborne hyperspectral camera at hand... don't you think it would help if you would provide some images? please reas [ask] as your post is pretty off-topic. using NDVI will only help if that desease causes a change in red and NIR reflectance. if it does it is reasonable, if not it is not. simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the vegetation mask you created is doing a good job of distinguishing between non vegetation and vegetation in the scene, I recommend that you create a vector file such as points or lines which correspond to individual potato plants or rows of plants in your scene. Once you have done that, you can buffer the geometry you have created in order to facilitate the calculation of zonal statistics within each polygon. If you tabulate the mean for a given layer in your multispectral raster file, that will give you the mean reflectance for a given band on a per plant or per row basis.

Because the reflectance values for the raw bands from multispectral sensors are sensitive to the lighting conditions (incident light) of the scene, it is more repeatable to use ratios of these bands such as NDVI to predict plant vigor (or stress in the case of diseased individuals).

I have developed a workflow that might help you extract the data you want:

http://blogs.oregonstate.edu/geog566spatialstatistics/2017/06/01/processing-multispectral-imagery-unmanned-aerial-vehicle-phenotyping-seedlings-common-garden-boxes-part-1/

http://blogs.oregonstate.edu/geog566spatialstatistics/2017/06/02/processing-multispectral-imagery-unmanned-aerial-vehicle-phenotyping-seedlings-common-garden-boxes-part-2/